# How to change the shortcut to move windows from Alt to Super/Meta?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

I use graphics software like GIMP, Inkscape & Blender extensively for my business. But most of them require the use of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in some way or the other. Come Ubuntu 11.10, I haven't been able to find any way to change the shortcut for window moving/resizing from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB/MMB to <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd>+LLM/MMB. This option was present in the 'Windows' settings in Gnome2, but it is not present anywhere in Gnome3. And yes, I have tried searching through the Shortcuts tab in Keyboard settings, its not there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).
2. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and navigate to the *Resize Window* plugin.
3. Click the *<Super>Button2* button and rebind the shortcut.

   [image]

Comment: It didn't work instantaneously after changing the settings for the Move pulgin and the Resize plugin, it took a logout->login to work. But yea, this was it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed too. The comments about logging out and  logging back in to get it to work also was important.

Comment: in Kubuntu 20.4 is this implemented without extra software. But i forget where

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 13.10 this worked for me:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`. Enter your password when prompted and after the installation is finished type `dconf-editor` to open the *Configuration Editor*.
2. Now either hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and use the hereby summoned field to search for `mouse-button-modifier` **or** navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` and find the same.
3. Change its value from `<Alt>` to something else (`<Super>` will probably work best) and enjoy your improved workflow!

NB: Leaving the field empty will get you stuck in drag-mode, unable to click the "Set to Default" button. You can bring the focus to this button by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until a fine orange rim shows up around it. Then press <kbd>Space</kbd> and repeat step 3.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least for Blender, you don't really need to go all this trouble.

Go to **File > User Preferences > Input**
In the search field type `edge`
Voila.

To cut this short story shorter the shortcuts on Blender are

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Select Mouse and
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Select Mouse respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Start Kubuntu v20.04 > Window Behavior > Window Actions

Answer (score -1):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager from Software Center. When you have installed (and opened) it, search there for "Unity plug-in" or something similar and click it. Select **Switcher** and there you can select the buttons which will open the Switcher.