# How can I disable the window manager's alt+drag action?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz

Tumblr uses <kbd>alt</kbd>+click to reblog, but Compiz uses <kbd>alt</kbd>+drag to move windows.  This is convenient for some, but I have literally never used Compiz's <kbd>alt</kbd>+drag and would like to disable it.  How can I get rid of the <kbd>alt</kbd>+click+drag function without disabling <kbd>alt</kbd> completely?

This is different from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/167193/37700) because I would like to *disable* this functionality, NOT move it to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Compiz settings manager if you don't have it already. In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now find and open the settings manager.  Find the **Move Window** plug-in.  (You don't want to *disable* the plug-in; if you do that you won't be able to move windows at all.)

Just change the first setting, Initiate Window Move. It can be change it from ***Alt*+Button 1** to ***Super*+Button 1**, but you stated that is not what you want, so just click on **Alt+Button 1** and uncheck *Enabled*.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I took so long to get back to you, I forgot about this question -_-.  I changed it to Ctrl+Alt+Drag as that didn't seem to be being used.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information: I tried to disable the **Alt+Button 1**, and all my window bars gone. This is not expected, I consider it a bug. And when I reboot my Ubuntu, the setting is recovered.

In my case, it cannot be disabled, but changing it into **Super+Button 1** works fine for me.