# Replicating Windows' Super + Arrow shortcuts for resizing windows

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, resize

So first, I'm sorry for trying to make Unity more like Windows, but as a long time Linux user that needed to move to Windows for work, but am now able to move back... I want this functionality so bad. (Fun note, my new machine is running way faster again)

On Windows you can press Super + Arrow keys to resize your window.

An example of this working almost perfectly on ubuntu 15.10 already is that you can drag your window to the right, top, or left to have it cover right half, full, or left half respectively.

I'd like to do this without dragging and use my arrow keys ie. Super + Right would cause the window to cover the right half of the screen.

I feel like it's as simple as finding the command that already does this and making keyboard shortcuts, but how do I find this command?

Comment: Simply use Ctrl+Alt+KP_2 /4/6/8 (Numpad arrows). should be a dupe of something.

Comment: yeah - can be done with this Q&A - http://askubuntu.com/questions/66125/how-to-change-the-shortcut-to-move-windows-from-alt-to-super-meta?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) for pointing in the direction of CompizConfig Settings Manager.

1. install compizconfig-settings-manager (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager)
2. Go to the Window Management > Grid
3. Enter shortcuts there
   [Screenshot of the compizconfig-settings-manager Grid settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9xdF.png)

edit:

Even more fun is this project: https://github.com/pkkid/pygrid giving the same functionality without compiz.

Answer (score 4):

I think, out of the box, Ubuntu  15.10 can do something very similar, except the key combo is `Ctrl + Super +` arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is built-in, Ctrl+Alt+Keypad. For example Ctrl+Alt+5 will maximize the window, Ctrl+Alt+7 will put at top left, Ctrl+Alt+6 on the right side and so on.

It is more flexible than Ctrl+Super+Arrow, which doesn't fully emulate Windows' Super + Arrow.

Comment: Built into what? Also not all machines have keypads.

Comment: built into ubuntu, no need to add anything.